# How can I prove this? If $\lim a_{2n}=\lim a_{2n+1}=L\in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim a_{n}=L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve this problem which seems obvious, but I am stuck I need a hint to start.

---

Prove that if $\lim a_{2n}=\lim a_{2n+1}=L\in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim a_{n}=L$, for any sequence $a_{n}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$; then there are $k_0$ and $k_1$ such that

1. for all $n\ge k_0$, $|a_{2n}-L|<\varepsilon$
2. for all $n\ge k_1$, $|a_{2n+1}-L|<\varepsilon$

What happens if $n>\max\{2k_0,2k_1+1\}$? If $n=2m$ is even, then $2m>2k_0$, so $|a_n-L|=|a_{2m}-L|<\varepsilon$. If $n$ is odd…

Comment: Correct I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the definition of a limit, start with the fact that "for every epsilon > 0" you can make two statements, and combine these two statements into one.

Comment: How can you relate $a_n$ with $a_2n$ and $a_{2n+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Idea/Hint:** Assume the sequence $a_n$ does not converge. Then there is a subsequence, that is "far" away from $L$. However, this subsequence has either a subsequence of the form $a_{2k}$ or $a_{2k+1}$ that converges to $L$.